# How to make a universal path with Python

Tags: python, path, directory

I am working on a Python application that I want to make installable in the future, so many people can use it. Right now, I want it to access a specific executable located on the app folder, which looks like this:

```
import subprocess
subrocess.call ('C:\Users\myusername\Desktop\Chester 2.0\Engine\Arena.exe')
```

If I leave it like that, when someone else runs it on their computer, the Python program won't find the file, for our usernames will be different. Is there a way in which it can access the file, regardless of the user's computer username?

Comment: Are you shipping the `Arena.exe` with your Python code? If yes, where are you running your script from? If no - how can you guarantee that all users have `Chester 2.0\Engine\Arena.exe` on their Desktop?

Comment: `os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'Arena.exe')`

Comment: @zwer I'm making an executable file that installs the program on the desktop of whoever downloads the program

Comment: @colspeed Does that alone open the file, or must I add something else afterwards

Answer (score 2):

```
from os.path import dirname
print(dirname(__file__))
```

outputs the absolute directory from which python is being run. that should get you going

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it by using the expanduser and os.path.join functions, now it looks like this:

```
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")
arena = os.path.join(home, "Desktop\Chester 2.0\Engine\Arena.exe")
subprocess.call (arena)
```